# Find specific spoken words in a video?

Tags: database, video

Is there any way I can go through the series of videos listed here:

http://archive.org/details/trumparchive&tab=collection

and find specific words matching with the time at which they were spoken?

**context** : 
I'm trying to make a compilation sort of bot, so my original idea was to look for a series of transcripts (preferably a database that contains the transcripts of the speeches with the approximate times at which words were spoken) and later use a program to find the videos, cut the clips with the words spoken, and then compile all the clips into one video.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. To avoid downvotes remember... This site is about **programming** questions. You need to have started something and have problems with your code to get advice (an _overflow_ leads to a computer crash). Tag the coding language used, show code that isn't working as expected, and so on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *"...Is there any way I can go through the series of videos listed here:*
>
> http://archive.org/details/trumparchive&tab=collection
>
> *and find specific words matching with the time at which they were
>   spoken?"*

If the video has subtitle file with it (*eg:* a SRT or WebVTT file) it might be possible.

Note: 
*The following below is done manually but after practicing, you can just write a program to do it automatically...*

Looking at the listed items : 
http://archive.org/details/trumparchive&tab=collection

We can pick one: [The O'Reilly Factor : FOXNEWSW : February](https://archive.org/details/FOXNEWSW_20170207_040300_The_OReilly_Factor)

And check the (html) source code to see if any `.srt` or `.vtt` files are listed :

```
href="/download/FOXNEWSW_20170207_040300_The_OReilly_Factor/FOXNEWSW_20170207_040300_The_OReilly_Factor.align.srt"
```

So the found subtitles are located at : 
 
https://archive.org/download/FOXNEWSW_20170207_040300_The_OReilly_Factor/FOXNEWSW_20170207_040300_The_OReilly_Factor.align.srt

Below is a sample of text. Now you know the words and specific times in video they're spoken.

```
1
00:00:00,0 --> 00:00:04,570
A "WASHINGTON TIMES" REPORTER. 
TONIGHT, WE HAVE A NUMBER OF 

2
00:00:04,572 --> 00:00:03,482
SUBJECTS THAT WE PRESENTED TO PRESIDENT 
TRUMP. 

3
00:00:03,484 --> 00:00:09,479
HERE THEY ARE. LET'S TALK ABOUT 
IRAN, YOUR 

4
00:00:09,481 --> 00:00:14,261
ASSESSMENT, DO YOU THINK WE ARE 
ON A COLLISION COURSE WITH THE 

5
00:00:14,263 --> 00:00:16,463
-- WITH THATED COUNTRY? PRESIDENT 
TRUMP: I THINK IT 

6
00:00:16,465 --> 00:00:18,221
WAS THE WORST DEAL I EVER SEE NEGOTIATED. 

7
00:00:18,223 --> 00:00:19,841
IT WAS IT DEAL THAT NEVER SHOULD 
HAVE BEEN NEGOTIATED.
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This helped a ton.